# Docker network interface interferes with mDNS address

Tags: docker, dns, mdns

Ever since I installed docker on my Ubuntu machine, I've been having problems with the mDNS address it advertises.

In order for me to ssh into my box without knowing the ip, I need to use `<hostname>.local`, which I need to have resolved to the eth0 interface. This was working up up until I configured docker.

I set /etc/docker/daemon.json to:

```
{
"bip": "192.168.254.1/24"
}
```

I start the docker daemon via the following simple command: `sudo service docker start`. I confirmed that the appropriate docker bridge (interface docker0) and that the firewall (ip tables) are as expected. All my services are communicating with each other as expected.

When I run `ifconfig`, I see that `docker0` advertises `192.168.254.1` and `eth0` advertises `10.14.146.62`.

When I ping `ping <hostname>.local` from within my ubuntu machine, it resolves to `10.14.146.62`. Same thing goes for other machines on the same network.

However, after some time (30 minutes), the following happens:

1. `ping <hostname>.local` starts returning unknown host
2. The advertised address (the one that other machines on the same network see when they try to ping `<hostname>` resolves to  `192.168.254.1`.

The only way to fix this (temporarily), is to:

1. Stop docker daemon
2. Restart avahi daemon
3. Start docker daemon

This returns me to the state where `<hostname>.local` resolves to `10.14.146.62` both internally and externally for some time.

I have tried modifying `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` to include the following without any successfull results:

```
allow-interfaces=eth0
deny-interfaces=docker0
```

I considered setting `iptables=false` in the docker configs, but I need my services to be reached externally.

Searching online led me to various solutions ranging from docker, firewall or avahi issues/configs. However, nothing has resulted in successful results yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: IIRC, there are some weird things that happen with avahi and `.local`. See if this helps: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352237/avahi-daemon-and-local-domain-issues